# How to move global reusable types to packages type in turborepo?

Tags: typescript, next.js, turborepo

For any app in `apps`, I need a `global.d.ts` having some types like this

```
interface Window{
    analytics: any;
}
```

It needs to be reusable and shifted to `packages/types` and can be used anywhere in apps.

I moved the Window type to `packages/types` but global types weren't working while importing in apps.

Answer (score 0):

Setting this up properly requires a few steps:

1. Create a `shared-types` package inside the `packages` folder of your monorepo
2. In the `package.json` of `shared-types`, define where the types are located:

```
{
    "name": "shared-types",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./index.js",
    "types": "./index.ts",
    "dependencies": {
        "typescript": "latest"
      }
}
```

3. Add the `shared-types` dependency to the apps that need it

```
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "shared-types": "*"
  },
```

4. Import the types you need

```
import { MyType } from "shared-types";
```

See this [Sharing Code](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code) and [Internal Packages](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code/internal-packages) sections of the Turborepo docs for more details.